# iOS 11 Drag and Drop File Path

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, uiimage, ios11

I am currently adding the ability for users to drag and drop in my app in iOS 11. The app supports dropping images into a UIImageView.

I would like to find the GPS data from the image that is being dropped in from the files app. I am using the code below to find the other data but cannot access the GPS data.

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession) {

    session.loadObjects(ofClass: UIImage.self) { imageItems in
        let images = imageItems as! [UIImage]
        self.imageView.image = images.first


        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(images.first!, 1.0)

        let imageData: NSData = data! as NSData
        let imageDataOptional: NSData? = data as? NSData
        if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData, nil) {
            let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil)! as NSDictionary

            print("Metadata: \(imageProperties)")
            print("DPI: \(imageProperties["DPIHeight"])")
            print("Width: \(imageProperties["PixelWidth"])")
            print("Height: \(imageProperties["PixelHeight"])")
        }
}
```

I am able to find the data by creating a CIImage from the file URL when choosing from the Document picker (see below).

```
let ciimg = CIImage(contentsOf: url)
 if ciimg != nil {
     let metadata = ciimg!.properties
     print("Meta: \(metadata)")
 }
```

Is it possible to access the GPS Data from the UIImage or find out the URL to do it the CIImage way and if so, how?

Comment: I have one suggestion which you can try. Instead of passing the image data just pass the local url for the image in Drag & Drop code just like any file. Try this should work.

Comment: Hello @Gagan_iOS that sounds good. Do you know how I would find the local URL when the image is dropped? I can't seem to access it or find any help on it. Thanks

Comment: where are the images? in your document directory, if Yes you can get the local path of the each image as URL. If you are copying from Photo library use this code NSURL* localUrl = (NSURL *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];